# using binary search on a file

Tags: ruby

I have this huge file with a few thousand lines, each line contains a number and a string after it. the numbers are already in order.

what I have so far is I scan through each line as an array and push them into another array, then I can perform binary search on this 2D array. is this the right way to do it? what about in terms of efficiency?

thanks

Comment: How many searches will you be performing? Are you able to reformat the file (say, into SQLite3) to speed future searches too? How often will the file change compared to how often you'll be searching the file?

Comment: it will only be a few searches, I'm doing this as an exercise. I'm just not sure if that's how you are suppose to perform binary search on a file. i can't edit the file

Answer (score 0):

Why do more work than necessary?

assuming the numbers are incremental and that they are really just an INDEX to the array

You have 3 choices that I can see.

Just access the file, then

1. binary search, a standard well defined alg available online.
2. if your strings are defined as the same length then you just need to index in to the required line using the formula byte address in file = (( number length + string length [ + CRLF ] ) * index) - 1 where CRLF is optional if you use Carriage Return & Line Feed to delimit lines - 1 because files start at byte ZERO not ONE
3. load them into a DataBase Management System and use the INDEX to access the string

the choice is yours, indexing is quicker, DBMS are more work but easier to manage try SQLite, binary search uses more time

Comment: Could you elaborate, how binary search can be applied to his case? I'm afraid I don't see it.